# Graphs such that every rotation system admits an embedding on a surface of small genus

Tags: graph-theory, graph-embeddings

Let $G$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph.
**What conditions on $G$ ensure that every rotation system of $G$ corresponds to an cellular embedding of $G$ on an oriened surface of small genus?**
(e.g. genus at most 2)

In particular, **what conditions on $G$ ensure that every rotation system of $G$ corresponds to a plane embedding of $G$?**

*Context:* I am interested in rotation systems with a specific property (biparite dual), let us call it property $P$. I would like to find at least a small class of planar graphs $G$ such that it suffices to check all plane embeddings of $G$ in order to test existence of rotation systems of $G$ with property $P$.

Comment: I posted this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52920/47855) in [cstheory.stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). I am unable to close the question by marking the reason as "question fits better in another stackexchange site" (only 3 sites are listed and cstheory is not one of them). I request to close the question.